# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n^2}$ exists and is independent of the choice of $a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has period 1, and for some $q\in(0,1)$:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq q|x-y|\quad \forall x,y$$

Let $g(x)=x+f(x)$, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$,define the following sequence:

$$a_1=a,\quad a_2=g(a_1),\quad a_3=g(a_2),\quad \dots,\quad a_{n+1}=g(a_n)$$

Show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n^2}$$

exists and does not depend on the choice of $a$.

I don't even know what is the possible approach, any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Can we prove that z(n) = f(a(n)) converges. If so then it is the answer to the question.

Comment: If $\{f=0\}$ if not empty, I think you can show that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded ($g$ will have a periodic sequence of fixed points, and since $g$ is monotonous, the orbits must stay between two fixed points, and so are bounded). If $f = b$ is constant, you can check that the limit is $b/2$. The general case is more tricky.

Comment: Related : [rotation numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number).

Comment: I don't think we can prove that $a_n$ converges in general (though it's possible we could prove that $f(a_n)$ converges). Pick $f(x)$ so that $f(1) = 1$. Then $f(n) = 1$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ and one can show by induction that if $a = 1$, then $a_n = n$ for all $n\geq 1$. So $f(a_n)$ converges but $a_n$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a complete solution. I hope someone can help to fully nail it down.

It will suffice using [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](http://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf) (*page 1*) for $b_n=2n-1,$ (because $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=n^2$) to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_n}{2n-1} < \infty.$ Again employing the other form of the theorem (*Remark in page 2*), it will suffice to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{(2n-1)-(2n-3)} < \infty$ which is to check $ \lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) < \infty.$

We know $f$ is [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), so is continuous. Therefore, it boils down to showing that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n < \infty.$ That is, proving that the iterated sequence of $g,$ i.e. $\{g^n(a)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ where $g^n(a)=g(g^{n-1}(a))$ is the $n$ times composition of $g$ with itself, has a limit. But the problem is that $g$ is a non-contracting Lipschitz, i.e. $|g(x)-g(y)| \leq (q+1)|x-y|$ where $1<q+1<2$ and this causes problems, of course.

The fact is that I haven't used the periodic condition on $f$ yet, and so I think, this should help resolve the issue, but I couldn't figure out how!